# Flutter & Firebase streamBuilder paginantion

Tags: firebase, flutter, pagination, google-cloud-firestore

so i've been looking for a way to add **pagination** to my app "**Chat**" for over a week now still no luck :(

this is my code

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder(
  //TODO add pagination later...

  stream: widget.messageDocRef
      .collection("Chat")
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(15)
      .snapshots(),

  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (!snapshot.hasData) {
      return Center(
        child: circularProgress(),
      );
    }
    final messages = snapshot.data.documents;
    for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.data.documents.length; i++) {
      DocumentSnapshot doc = snapshot.data.documents.elementAt(i);
      print(doc.metadata.isFromCache
          ? "DATA FROM CACHE"
          : "DATA FROM INTERNET");
    }

    List<MessageBubble> messagesBubble = [];
    for (var message in messages) {
      final docId = message.documentID;

      final messageText = message.data['content'];

      final messageSender = message.data['from'];

      final messageType = message.data['type'];

      final messageBubble = MessageBubble(
        messageDocRef: widget.messageDocRef,
        docId: docId,
        type: messageType,
        text: messageText,
        isMe: widget.currentUser.id == messageSender,
      );
      messagesBubble.add(messageBubble);
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: ListView(
        physics: const AlwaysScrollableScrollPhysics(),
        reverse: true,
        controller: this._scrollController,
        padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20.0, horizontal: 10.0),
        children: messagesBubble,
      ),
    );
  },
);}
```

My init State

```
void initState() {
super.initState();
_scrollController.addListener(() {
  double maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
  double currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
  if (maxScroll == currentScroll) {
    print("get more products");
  }
});}
```

**MessageBubble** is a Class to show each message in a seperate bubble.

Until now everything is working great!. but i need to implement pagination and **not losing** the **streamBuilder real time update** ("Showing new message", "Deleting deleted messages" ...etc).

i literally dont know how i'm going to pull this one off i tried **using multiple queries** still no luck.

i want the user to be able to see **older messages** as he **scrolls up** and to see **newer messages** when he **scrolls down**.

HELP!!!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try this [method](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/pagination-in-flutter-using-firebase-cloud-firestore/) or this [one](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/pagination-in-flutter-with-firebase-firestore-96d6cc11aef2)?

Don't limit the documents, make it variable and can be updated every time.

Comment: Hi, yes i saw the first method, but it won't work because i'm using a streamBuilder and his using a listView.Builder. i don't want to lose StreamBuilder realtime update ability.

Answer (score 0):

Make your stream something like this...

```
int _limit = 20;
...
stream: widget.messageDocRef
      .collection("Chat")
      .orderBy('timestamp', descending: true)
      .limit(_limit)
      .snapshots(),
```

Then add this listener to your scrollController:

```
final ScrollController _scrollController = new ScrollController();
...
void initState() {
   _scrollController.addListener(_scrollListener);
}
...
void _scrollListener() {
  if (_scrollController.offset >= _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent &&
      !_scrollController.position.outOfRange) {
    print("at the end of list");
    setState(() {
        _limit +=20;
    });
  }
}

...
ListView(
   ...
   controller: _scrollController
   ...
)
```

I still don't figure out how to put a progress indicator on the end of the screen but this is the best work around I can think of.